# Confusion between operation and relation: Clarification needed

Tags: relations

I'm doing some old exams and found following question:

> Set $S={{1,2,3}}$ is given. Provide an
>   example of binary operation in set S,
>   binary relation in set S and a
>   function $f:S\rightarrow R$.

So, I'm thinking about $+_4$ as operation, but wouldn't it be a relation too? I can take ordered pair from $S$ and for every ordered pair associate an element form $S$ with every pair.

For the third part, I'm thinking about $y=x*1.25$ or something similar, but that part isn't so problematic for me.

I did read the Wikipedia articles, but the difference between operations  and relations isn't clear to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A binary operation is a function from $S\times S \to S$ such as addition, multiplication or anything really.

A binary relation is just a subset of $S^2$, that is not necessarily a function and it doesn't have to include all the elements of $S$ in one way or another.

A function $f\colon S\to R$ is a relation, this time it's a subset of $S\times R$ however it satisfies a certain property, if you take some $s \in S$ then there is only a unique ordered pair with $s$ in it, so if you have $\langle s,r_1\rangle$ as well $\langle s,r_2\rangle$ then you can say that $r_1 = r_2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is clear to me now.

Comment: Is a binary relation on a set S a function f: SxS -> {true, false}?

Comment: @TigerTV.ru That's one way of looking at it. Sure.

Comment: Exactly, true being that an ordered pair of element is in the subset formed by the relation, false if the ordered pair is not in the subset formed by the relation

Answer (score 3):

BINARY OPERATION: A binary operation is a rule that combines the elements or any mathematical objects of the same kind and produces the third element or object of that kind.

BINARY RELATION:  A binary relation on a set $A$ is a collection of ordered pair of elements  of $A$. Or, simply a subset of Cartesian  product, $A\times A$.

FUNCTION: A function is a particular type of relation  which maps every point in a domain to a unique point in the range.